# How to select values from one column in function of the values of multiple other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the original data:

```
     Name       Wine      Year
0    Mark     Volnay      1983
1    Mark     Volnay      1979
3    Mary     Volnay      1979
4    Mary     Volnay      1999
5    Mary  Champagne      1993
6    Mary  Champagne      1989
```

I would like to be able to get the value of `Year` in function of the values of `Name` and `Wine`. It would return all the values in the `Year` column of the entries that have the corresponding values in the `Name` and `Wine` columns.

For example: with the key `['Mark', 'Volnay']` I would get the values `[1983, 1979]`

I tried manipulating the data and here is the best I could get.

Keep one instance of each key:

```
     Name       Wine      Year
1    Jean     Volnay      1979
4  Pierre     Volnay      1999
6  Pierre  Champagne      1989
```

Remove the `Year` column

```
     Name       Wine
1    Jean     Volnay
4  Pierre     Volnay
6  Pierre  Champagne
```

Get the values in a list

```
[['Mark', 'Volnay'], ['Mary', 'Volnay'], ['Mary', 'Champagne']]
```

I now have the keys I need, but I can't get the values in the original dataframe in function of the value of the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `groupby` with `get_group`

```
def getyear(datafrae,keys:list):
    values = df.groupby(['Name', 'Wine']).get_group(tuple(key))['Year']
    dedupvalues = [*dict.fromkeys(values).keys()] #incase of duplicates
    return dedupvalues
```

---

```
keys = ['Mark', 'Volnay']
print(getyear(df,keys))
[1983, 1979]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `set_index` and then `loc`:

```
key = ['Mark', 'Volnay']
lst = df.set_index(['Name', 'Wine']).loc[key, 'Year'].tolist()
```

Output:

```
>>> lst
[1983, 1979]
```